# JavaScript location.href doesn't add record to browser history

Tags: javascript, html

There are three pages, A, B and C. 
A has a  tag  whose href redirects to B.
B has JavaScript Code and redirects to C.
When in C, I click browser back button, browser redirects to A. Why not B ? Thank you in advance.

Test Links
Page A: http://o17o2o.com:8000/article-href.html

Page A

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/href-redirect.html">click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Page B

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>waiting</title>
</head>
<body>
    Page B
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = '/original.html';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your code? How are the redirects one? Do they use `window.location.href` or `history.replaceState`?

Comment: can you share your code.

Comment: It would be annoying. If you press back while on C you would then (after javascript redirect) again be on C.

Comment: he's using `window.location.href`

Comment: @Dymos the code is online at the URL he posted.

Comment: Have you tried ` window.history.go(-1)`

Comment: He's not asking how to go back to page B, but rather why is it not going back to it.

Comment: try window.load in page B `function load() {
       window.location.href = '/original.html';
      }
      window.onload = load;`

Answer (score 4):

location.href redirect will only add to browser history if it is from user initiated action. Here you are calling it on onload event so it wont be added to history

user History.pushState to insert in browser history

Comment: Do you have a link to a specification to support your argument?

Comment: Thank you. And if I wrap my code in setTimeout, location.href redirect adds to browser history, too .

Comment: no setTImeout wont do it...try this ...$(document).ready( 
function() 
{ 
   $('#redirectdiv').click( function() {document.location.href='b.com';}); 
} 
);

Answer (score 0):

I have an observation here. If we add a setTimeout before calling location.href programmatically, say a 2 sec delay, the current page gets added in the history. Looks like this behavior is somewhat asynchronous and it happens in all browser. I wonder why this bug is not solved for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Manually tested:
If user didn't interact with the document first (like keydown, click, but not wheel),
calling location.href=xx programmatically, the current page will not added to the history record.